# Can there be an effectively generated consistent theory that extends PA and be consistently extended by its own completeness and consistency?

Tags: lo.logic

[The question has been edited]

Can we have an effectively generated consistent theory $T$, that extends $\sf PA$, such that:

$T + \\ \forall \mathcal S \, [\exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \mathcal S \urcorner) \oplus \exists y: \operatorname {Proof}_T(y, \operatorname {neg}(\ulcorner \mathcal S \urcorner))]$

is consistent?

Where "$\operatorname {neg}$" is Rosser's negation function. and "$\oplus$" is exclusive disjunction.

In other words, can $T$ be consistently extended by its own completeness and consistency?

Comment: No. Gödel-Rosser theorems *are* about internal incompleteness/consistency.

Comment: @godelian,  let $\rho$ denote the Rosser sentence, then we have $T \not \vdash \rho$ and $T \not \vdash \neg \rho$, but we can have $\exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \rho \urcorner)$, I mean why should that lead to $\exists y: \operatorname {Proof}_T(y, \ulcorner \neg \rho \urcorner)$? If it doesn't, then I don't see how Gödel-Rosser theorems go against the result here.

Comment: Your exclusive disjunction implies $\text{Con}_T$, precisely because it is exclusive, and so you are asking for a effective consistent theory $T$ that proves its own consistency.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, is $\text{Con}_T$ a metatheoretical statement? Or is it in-theoretic?

Comment: $\text{Con}_T$ is an assertion in the object theory, that is, the internal notion. This is always what is meant when discussing whether a theory proves its own consistency. There is in general no way to formulate the metatheoretic notion in the object theory, and so it makes no sense to ask whether the theory proves its own metatheoretic consistency.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I see. I've edited the question.

Comment: The answer is still the same. The formalized version of the usual proof of the Gödel–Rosser theorem shows that if you take for $S$ the Rosser sentence of $T$, then the formal $T$-provability of either $S$ or $\neg S$ implies the formal $T$-provability of the other one (i.e., formal inconsistency).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Looks like we posted the same thing at the same time.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, so if we have $\exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \rho \urcorner)$, then we have $\exists y: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \operatorname {neg} (\ulcorner \rho \urcorner))$, it seems that this is even provable in $\sf PA$, but why? I mean if we have $\exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \rho \urcorner)$ then this doesn't necessarily entail $T \vdash \rho$ since $x$ may be non-standard. That said, why we cannot have $T \not \vdash \rho$ and $T \not \vdash \neg \rho$, and just $\exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \rho \urcorner)$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek,... where $\rho$ is the Rosser's sentence.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Just follow the usual argument. If there exists a proof of $\rho$ or its negation, let $x$ be the least proof of either of them. If $x$ is a proof of $\neg\rho$, then (by the definition) $\rho$ holds, and being a $\Sigma_1$-sentence, it is provable. If $x$ is a proof of $\rho$, then the dual $\Sigma_1$-sentence $\rho^\bot={}$“there is a proof of $\rho$ smaller than any proof of $\neg\rho$” holds, hence it is provable, and since $\rho^\bot$ implies $\neg\rho$, $\neg\rho$ is provable. Either way, both $\rho$ and $\neg\rho$ are provable.

Comment: I'll use "$T \vdash$" to denote metatheoretic provability in $T$, and "$\operatorname {Proof}_T$" for theoretic provability in $T$. Now if we have $\exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x,\ulcorner \neg \rho \urcorner)$, now by definition $\neg \rho$ is the statement $\exists x \, ( \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \rho \urcorner) \land \forall y (\operatorname {Proof}_T(y, \ulcorner \neg \rho \urcorner) \to x < y))$, now in order to pass to $\exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \rho \urcorner)$ you need to have ..

Comment: ...$\exists z: \operatorname {Proof}_T (z, \ulcorner \neg \rho  \to \exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \rho \urcorner )\urcorner)$. How you get that?

Comment: $\def\pf#1#2{\operatorname{Proof}_T(#1,\ulcorner#2\urcorner)}$I intended $\rho$ to be equivalent to $\exists x\,(\pf x{\neg\rho}\land\forall y\le x\,\neg\pf y\rho)$, in which case $\neg\rho$ is not $\exists x\,(\pf x{\rho}\land\forall y\le x\,\neg\pf y{\neg\rho})$ (this is what I denote $\rho^\bot$), but $\forall x\,(\pf x{\neg\rho}\to\exists y<x\,\pf y\rho)$. But this does not matter; if you use the dual definition as in your comment, then $\neg\rho\to\exists x\,\pf x\rho$ is an instance of the tautology $\exists x\,(A(x)\land B(x))\to\exists x\,A(x)$, hence its formal provability is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the edited question is No, there is no such theory $T$, because the incompleteness theorem is provable in PA and hence also in $T$. The theory $T$ will prove that there is no effective complete consistent theory of arithmetic, and in particular, $T$ will prove that $T$ itself (as defined by its effective algorithm) cannot have the property of your exclusive disjunction clause.